# I need android layout configurations

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

[image]

70% 30% The layout was made with the weightsum of LinearLayout. But, image layout can not be overlay on top of it. Did I do the wrong approach?

Comment: I would suggest you to use ConstraintLayout. It is very efficient in handling such cases. Also, please do post your code that you tried so I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ContraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) for more flexibility.

Use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` attribute to denote the height in percentage

You can use to following code to align `Image` between two layouts.

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout1"
```

Here is the full code to achieve the layout you mentioned.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout2"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.7"             // 70% of height
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"             // 30% of height
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        // To align image between layout1 and layout2  
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/layout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: sample]

Comment: wow! great! Thanks a million.
I couldn’t have done it without you.